# Blazor Server WebApp - High memory usage under Linux

Tags: .net, linux, memory, blazor, malloc

I am seeing extremely high memory usage from my dotnet application when running under Linux. The memory is also never released.
When users use my web app they do require large amounts of memory (1-2 GB to run a report) but when they close the tab resources are released and I would expect dotnet to do the same to some extent.

What I'm experiencing is near 90-95% memory usage from my dotnet app.

### Problems

1. I'm unable to determine if my server is at peak memory usage or dotnet is holding onto memory as there is little memory pressure from other processes.
2. dotnet memory dumps are huge and I don't think they should be. (~5-6 GB download vs ~30-300 MB in used objects when analysed)

### Mem Diagnostics

```
root@a9f25bad2d02:~/site/wwwroot# dotnet-counters monitor

[System.Runtime]
    % Time in GC since last GC (%)                                         0    
    Allocation Rate (B / 10 sec)                                     209,648    
    CPU Usage (%)                                                          0    
    Exception Count (Count / 10 sec)                                       0    
    GC Committed Bytes (MB)                                              105    
    GC Fragmentation (%)                                                  43.752
    GC Heap Size (MB)                                                     68    
    Gen 0 GC Count (Count / 10 sec)                                        0    
    Gen 0 Size (B)                                                19,577,728    
    Gen 1 GC Count (Count / 10 sec)                                        0    
    Gen 1 Size (B)                                                 1,608,856    
    Gen 2 GC Count (Count / 10 sec)                                        0    
    Gen 2 Size (B)                                                49,073,776    
    IL Bytes Jitted (B)                                            4,471,180    
    LOH Size (B)                                                  26,161,384    
    Monitor Lock Contention Count (Count / 10 sec)                         0    
    Number of Active Timers                                               15    
    Number of Assemblies Loaded                                        5,110    
    Number of Methods Jitted                                          64,067    
    POH (Pinned Object Heap) Size (B)                                706,440    
    ThreadPool Completed Work Item Count (Count / 10 sec)                 17    
    ThreadPool Queue Length                                                0    
    ThreadPool Thread Count                                                4    
    Time spent in JIT (ms / 10 sec)                                        0 
    Working Set (MB)                                                   5,773 
    
    
root@a9f25bad2d02:~/site/wwwroot# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7817        6858         121          19         837         740
Swap:          4095        2156        1939

root@a9f25bad2d02:~/site/wwwroot# top
Tasks:  11 total,   2 running,   8 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.5 us,  0.7 sy, 50.4 ni, 45.3 id,  2.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7817.4 total,     89.3 free,   7262.5 used,    465.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   1676.2 free,   2419.8 used.    341.3 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                           
   74 root      30  10 9812340   5.4g  19812 t   0.0  70.7  21:22.97 dotnet                                                                                                                                       
 1908 root      30  10   13948    708    540 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.18 sshd                                                                                                                                         
 1910 root      30  10    5752   2040   1808 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 bash                                                                                                                                         
 2526 root      30  10    9780   3448   2972 R   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 top
```

As you see from the `dotnet-counters monitor` the working set is around 5.7 GB whereas the total of bytes used from all generations, as well as the Large and Pinned Object Heaps is only around 120 Mb.

Which is corroborated with an analysis of a memory dump which was 5 Gb in size.

[image: Mem Analysis]

### What have I done already

1. I've switched between Server and Workstation GC - no real difference.
2. I've performed a dotnet dump dotnet-dump collect --type Full and searched for any memory pressure from within my app.
3. I've added dotnet counters into my app to report on Gen 0, 1, 2, LOH and Heap size - all values do go up but come down again after the user leaves the site.
4. I've switched my app to Windows and see that Memory usage is more 'normal' and memory is freed after a while.
5. I've run the app with `dotnet-counters collect` and simulated typical user load. I have graphed the result of `GC Committed Bytes` by time below.

[image: GC Committed Bytes by Time for typical user load]

### Background

- The App is running as Blazor Server
- The App is being hosted in Azure under a Linux App Service Plan (P1v3 to be precise)

Comment: "memory is freed after a while" sounds  like things are timing out rather that being disposed correctly.  "do require large amounts of memory (1-2 GB to run a report)".  Go through this.  Build unit tests.  Watch memory usage.   If you're releasing resources correctly the GC should be cleaning up quickly.   Are you using the `IDbContextFactory` and short lived connections.  Are you disposing things that need disposing.

Comment: "Go through this. Build unit tests. Watch memory usage."
I have added a further point to what I have done with regard to simulating typical user load and watching GC usage.
"Are you disposing things that need disposing." You can see from the mem analysis that the overall memory usage in the GC is just 33 Mb so I am confident my app is cleaning up resources after users leave the site.

Comment: Without any code we can only guess. No memory analysis will show whether you use `using` blocks properly, or how you use MemoryStream, List.Add or string operations, the main causes of orphaned objects. Or You didn't even mention whether this is a Blazor WASM or Blazor Server application

Comment: What you posted shows that a lot of orphaned objects remain in memory until the GC runs. The phrase `1-2 GB to run a report` points to inefficient code. That could be lots of string operations generating a lot of temporary objects, or `List.Add` operations that result in a lot of buffer reallocations. Or the report code may be buggy, loading entire tables in memory instead of just the rows and columns that are really needed. If you tried to "fix" a LINQ-to-SQL translation exception with `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` you're loading entire tables in memory

Comment: The fact this runs more normally under Windows (i.e., memory from the server is freed) suggests it's an issue with the CLR under Linux rather than some of the code I'm running. What I'm trying to discover is if something is misconfigured or someone else has had the same problem under linux.
You are right I have not stated Blazor WASM vs Server- I'll update the question.

Comment: I agree about the differences between Windows and Linux, but I can't believe there's a  fundamental problem otherwise it would have come to light already [just a difference in how it handles and releases memory].  The comments above are all relevant.   You may not believe you have memory leaks, but you almost certainly do.   "all values do go up but come down again after the user leaves the site".  They should come down when the query completes and the page rendered.  Any query should open a `DbContext`, query, and release the resources.  Surely the resultant in memory data sets aren't 1-2 GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause for my issue was not to do with my app or event dotnet at all - it was to do with `glib malloc`. There is some dynamic sizing of memory allocation blocks going on in malloc and when an app uses lots of memory, fragmentation occurs and the memory is reluctantly released. A better write-up can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13301#issuecomment-535641506

This is not just affecting me but other programs are affected outside of dotnet. E.g.,

- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/49317
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13702
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13301
- https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/8993
- https://github.com/ErythroGuild/irene/issues/315
- https://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4117#c39
- https://thehftguy.com/2020/05/21/major-bug-in-glibc-is-killing-applications-with-a-memory-limit/

There appears to be 2 workarounds either fix the size of `glibc.malloc.trim_threshold` to stop it being dynamic or reduce the number of arenas via `glibc.malloc.arena_max` as the default number is `8 * NumOfCores`. More information can be found here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory-Allocation-Tunables.html

Ultimately I chose to set the environment variable `MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_=131072` which fixed the problem for me.

In Azure you can conveniently use the Configuration to do this,
[image]

Which I can confirm is set via bash,

```
kudu_ssh_user@ff3d088f400d:/$ env | grep MALLOC
APPSETTING_MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_=131072
MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_=131072
```

And now I can see memory being released in my Web App ,
[image]